# The Network Adapter could not establish the connection, how to fix?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

```
Class.forName ("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/SID", "username", "password");
```

I keep getting the error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
```

What does this mean, and how can I fix it?

I'm using the `ojdbc14.jar`,
I'm not experienced in using Oracle but I'm trying to connect to one of the databases.

Please help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is most likely caused by one of these factors:

- You are using the wrong URL
- The wrong port number or IP address (or DNS host name) was used
- The listener is not configured properly
- The listener process (service) is not running. You can re-start it with the "lsnrctl start" command or on Windows by starting the listener service.

In your case you need to change / to : as you are using SID not service name.

```
"jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:SID"
```

Comment: this is literally copy and paste of someone else's post, I can assure the credentials I'm using are correct and the service is indeed running as I can access it through Excel

Comment: what is SIDHERE?SID or Service name?

Comment: Its just a placeholder for the SID, I use the SID in my program

Comment: In your case you need to change / to : as you are using SID not service name.Try it.

Comment: We recommend using the fully qualified connection string URL as shown below. jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(HOST=myhost)(PORT=1521)(PROTOCOL=tcp))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=myorcldbservicename))).

Answer (score 1):

Can you try with:

```
Class.forName ("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection
            ("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/SID", "username", "password");
```

Comment: this would cause a class not found exception since I'm using oracle

Comment: Adding the "//" was actually my initial try, both causes the network adapter error :(

Comment: Can you check if database is up on the same port as you are mentioning in your program, using telnet like : `telnet localhost 1521`

Comment: It's running on port 15980, I reflect that on my code

Comment: If it running on `15980` then why you are using `1521`?

Comment: I'm not using 1521, I just posted 1521 here just for reference

Comment: then try `telnet localhost 15980` and let us know if it shows blank screen or not

Comment: Sorry but I'm not familiar with `telnet localhost 15980`, is this code or something I put in command line? I'm on a Windows Environment so the command doesn't work

Comment: first enable the telnet on windows and then run the same command from command line

Comment: some of the features were not enabled, and the command still doesn't work in cmd